# Alternative for hook_node_submit()

Tags: nodes, 8

What is an alternative to `hook_node_submit()` for Drupal 8?

Comment: You can use form_alter and add a submit handler.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [related change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2420295) has to say:

> Instead of the submit hook, an #entity_builder callback should be used to map form values to an entity (or better; use a field with a widget). If the submit hook is not about mapping values to the entity, register a custom #submit callback on the submit button and put your logic there.

And here are the related code samples:

```
// Implements HOOK_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // For entity builders.
  $form['#entity_builders'][] = 'mymodule_node_builder';
  // For submit callbacks.
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_node_form_submit';
}

function mymodule_node_builder($entity_type, NodeInterface $node, &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $parent = $form_state->getValue('menu', 'parent');
  if ($parent) {
    list($node->menu['menu_name'], $node->menu['plid']) = explode(':', $parent);
  }
}

function mymodule_node_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  mymodule_do_something($node);
}
```

Comment: I want to save a value to an required field before its submitted in content type

Comment: Then you don't want a submit hook, you want a validate hook